# Unable to install package post adding ppa

Tags: apt, live-usb, ppa, 19.04, woeusb

I've been trying to create a bootable pen drive for the windows 10 may update on my ubuntu laptop for my PC. I'm running the 19.04 version of ubuntu. Since the windows iso needs special processes to be burned to the usb I'm required to install the woe-usb open source package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

But I keep receiving this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package woeusb
```

I've searched throughout Stack Exchange and ask ubuntu but I have ended up empty-handed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2020-06-21**

The PPA `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` currently contains packages for Ubuntu up to 20.04 LTS.

So you can install WoeUSB as usual:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get install woeusb
```

---

Also the WoeUSB package exists [in `ppa:tomtomtom/woeusb` PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Etomtomtom/+archive/ubuntu/woeusb?field.series_filter=disco):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomtomtom/woeusb
sudo apt-get install woeusb
```

---

Note: to prepare this answer I have used special PPA search page on LaunchPad.net - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas .

Comment: Although it was installed ubuntu doesn't open up the app

Comment: Its GUI executable is named `woeusbgui`. Did you tried to open it from terminal? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: woeusbgui: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
.

Comment: This is the error that it gives me should I open it as adminstrator using the ''sudo" command

Comment: This library is installable with `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-0v5`. On my system it was previously installed. Added this to the answer. Will contact PPA owners.

Comment: The `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` now have the WoeUSB package. So I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency is added in version 3.3.0-1 in my ppa.

Thx for reporting the issue.