# How To Create Windows Installation USB In Linux?

Tags: windows, live-usb, winusb

I tried some programs to make a Windows bootable installation USB, like using Etcher, Rufus, WinUSB and more, but none of them are working ( WinUSB is not installing and gives me an error while I'm trying to add installation repository with this command):

```
xii69@xii69:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
Cannot add PPA: 'This PPA does not support focal'.
```

Somebody can tell me how to fix WinUSB installation or some other programs for this job?

Comment: I have found that the only system capable of creating a bootable Windows installation USB device is Windows itself. You have two options: (1) Grab [a Windows VM from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) and run it with VirtualBox or VMware, use USB pass-through, and write the installation media (2) borrow a friend/family-member's Windows machine to create the USB stick

Comment: @matigo Nice thanks, and I have some more questions, I checked your page and it seems you are a professional Linux user, Do you have Discord? I want to ask you 1 or 2 more questions. My Discord ID : `xii69#2344

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install package post adding ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145667/unable-to-install-package-post-adding-ppa) WoeUSB from ppa:tomtomtom/woeusb should work.

Comment: @N0rbert no didn't work, but anyway thanks.

Comment: Try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It works with Windows 7 - 11 iso files. - Which version of Ubuntu are you running and which version of Windows are you trying to install? Are you sure that the Windows iso file was downloaded successfully?

Comment: @sudodus Hello, I'm using Mint Linux version 20.2 Cinnamon edition, and I'm trying to make a bootable USB with Windows 10 64bit all in one iso file, I downloaded this iso directly from Microsoft and yes I'm sure its successfully downloaded, anyway ... thanks.

Comment: I have successfully used [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/) to boot my Windows installer from an Ubuntu-created USB.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you a lot :D

Comment: @xii69, [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) is developed for Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours, but works in Linux Mint too, so it should work to create a Windows 10 installer drive for you. - But please explain what you mean by 'all in one iso file'. Do you mean a multiboot iso file? In that case Ventoy is a good choice. Mkusb, Woeusb and Rufus make dedicated USB boot drives, not multiboot drives.

Comment: @sudodus Hello, for All In One I mean all windows editions in 1 iso file like an iso with windows 10 pro, home and enterprice

Comment: @karel Hello, no didn't but thank you anyway.

Comment: @xii69, I *think* such an iso file will work with mkusb. If not, please let me know and specify that iso file (how to download it), so that I can make mkusb work with it.

Comment: @sudodus Hello, C.S.Cameron's answer with pictures helped me a lot and yea works thanks, but i have another problem with my USB

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383263/usb-null-non-exist-problem-please-help

and about ISO file, its Windows 10 64Bit all in one, I downloaded this file directly from Microsoft

Comment: @xii69, You deleted that question. Is the problem solved? If not, analyze the problem with the USB drive according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and I think you can make it work again. (It is possible that the hardware of the USB drive was damaged, such things can happen anytime, but it is more likely that there was 'confusion' or a damaged file system.)

Comment: Questions about Linux Mint are on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Installing Windows using mkusb-plug

- Install mkusb: [Can I install mkusb in Ubuntu live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250091/can-i-install-mkusb-in-ubuntu-live-usb/1250149#1250149) Works on internal Ubuntu drives and on Live Ubuntu USB's
- Click mkusb-plug icon to start and then proceed as follows:

[image]

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[[image]]4]

Step 4

[image]

Step 5

[image]

Step 6

[image]

Step 7

[image]

Step 8

You should now have a USB installer ready to infect your computer with Windows

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: Hello again, a long time elapsed and I need this mkusb again, but this time I'm using Kali 2021.4 and I can't install with that commands you said, I searched a lot for Debian & Kali installation but nothing of them worked, most helpful tutorial was [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian)this link, I added the link manually at the directory and added the key, but gives me error for adding the key and I can't use this, can you help me this time again ? thanks
error : my text is too long i post it in another command for u

Comment: error :
`┌──(xii69㉿xii69)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 54B8C8AC
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.8X4E6lCx1v/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 54B8C8AC
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`